# Java: DataOutputStream through socket is wrong on other side (which is Python)

Tags: java, python, sockets, hwnd

I've got a `Socket`, `s` and an `long`, `1312992`.

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
out.writeLong(hwnd);
out.flush();
```

Doing

```
self.hwnd, = struct.unpack('!Q', self.appletconn.recv(8))
print(self.hwnd)
```

on the (python) receiving side prints out `51`. I presume something's wrong with my sending code.

Thanks.

Comment: What's `self.appletconn.recv(8)` by itself?

Comment: @nneonneo `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003'`

Comment: Yep, then it is probably on the sending end. (Just checking). Do other things get written correctly?

Comment: @nneonneo This is the only time I've tried using the `DataOutputStream`, all other times I've used `PrintWriter` and sent text.

Comment: Are you mixing `PrintWriter` and `DataOutputStream` on the same socket?

Comment: 1312992 is 1408E0 in hex, so that is what you should be expecting. If you're not seeing that there is something wrong with the *receiving* code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a packet capture tool like tcpdump or wireshark and check what is going on the wire. I am guessing, you might be mixing text and binary on sending and/or receiving side.